# how to turn windows service on if its off. control it from webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, service

i want to turn windows service on when it is off.
is it possible to make via code from web application with c#?
i am using asp.net mvc and c#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [`ServiceController` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx).

Comment: and here is some example http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/06/14/windows-service-administration-with-net-part-3-controlling-your-service/

Answer (score 6):

Its possible to do it but its unlikely that you want to run your website under an account which has enough rights to be able to Start/Stop services.  You can use the ServiceController class to start a service [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here an example:

```
                var sc = new ServiceController("Your service name");
                sc.Stop();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
                logger.Info("service stopped.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class.