# how to check if windows service is on/off from webapplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, service

hot to check if windows service is on/off from webapplication?
i am using asp.net mvc and c#. 
do i need some administrator privilegies to check status of windows service?

Comment: You could technically use [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx), though I'm not sure how far you'd get with security. You would probably have better luck hosting a very watered down WCF service and ping it as a check.

Comment: Dup of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233790/how-to-turn-windows-service-on-if-its-off-control-it-from-webapplication

Comment: yes, but i need other information. is it really ServiceController? quiet powerfull class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) will help you out.  I am not sure of the privileges of viewing vs. starting/stopping are.